# Compiling an OpenGL app written in C with Emscripten and Regal - Having compiling issues with Regal

Tags: c, opengl, compilation, cross-compiling, emscripten

I've been trying to compile a old game I wrote using OpenGl 2.1 and C. I wanted to try compiling it with Emscripten. So I went ahead and built the tools and SDK from sauce, compiled some test examples and everything checks out.

Long story short, Emscripten doesn't support old/non ES OpenGL too well (understandably) but then I read that Regal can work well as an interpreter.

Here's where I'm stuck, I have no clue how to combine the Regal. When I simply replace the GL, GLU and GLUT header references, I get the same Emscripten compiler warnings, just replaced with what seems to be the Regal equivalents:

> warning: unresolved symbol: rglPopMatrix
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglShadeModel
>   warning: unresolved symbol: glutGameModeString
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglLightfv
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglMatrixMode
>   warning: unresolved symbol: glutSolidSphere
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglLoadIdentity
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglClear
>   warning: unresolved symbol: glutSolidCube
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglTranslatef
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglRotatef
>   warning: unresolved symbol: glutEnterGameMode
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglMaterialfv
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglPolygonMode
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglPushMatrix
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglGetFloatv
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglViewport
>   warning: unresolved symbol: rglEnable

Am I missing something simple or vital here? Even an explanation as to why this doesn't/shouldn't work would be awesome.

If I manage to get any further with this, will post an update.

P.S. Compiler tools I'm using - OS is Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

https://github.com/p3/regal

EDIT 2
I'm fairly sure this is an issue linking with Regal, but I can't seem to find any sort of decent documentation or methods apart from the simple "Include GL/Regal.H" and "Link with libRegal.so" statements on the github page. When I built the Regal package I used the standard "make all" command. Would I need to do anything further than that?

EDIT 1
What my current makefile looks like

> INCLUDES = -L/home/BlastingKap/TestLibs/regal-master/lib/linux -lRegal -lRegalGLU -lRegalGLUT -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0
>
> VoxelCannon: VoxelCannon.c graphics.c visible.c graphics.h
>       ./emcc VoxelCannon.c graphics.c visible.c -o VoxCannon.html $(INCLUDES)

Comment: Did you link `libRegal.a`? (Something like `emcc -lRegal foo.c`)

Comment: Yes, I'm linking in libRegal, libRegalGLU and libRegalGLUT (doesn't seem to matter if I link the last two).

Answer (score 0):

To get rid from warnings `unresolved symbol: rgl*` you should compile Regal with REGAL_NAMESPACE=1. Even more for emscripten you should compile Regal for emscripten. Use this command:

```
    emmake make -f Makefile SYSTEM=emscripten
```

After that add to linker static libs from `lib/emscripten` (libRegallib).

P.S. I also trying to use Regal+emscripten, and I successfully build my project. However when I run it I does not see anything.

**UPD.** You should call `RegalMakeCurrent((RegalSystemContext)1);` to associate emscripten gl context with regal gl context. Like this:

```
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("app");

    RegalMakeCurrent((RegalSystemContext)1);

    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
```